# SQL query for the below expected output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables

```
TABLE1
ASSET   OWNER1  OWNER2
-----------------------
note     111     444
pen      333     555
book     222     666


TABLE2
OWNER   NAME
-------------
111     Avani
444     Jack
333     Jyothi
555     John
222     Nilehi
666     Mohit
```

What should be SQL query to get the following output?

```
ASSET  OWNER1  NAME    OWNER2  NAME
------------------------------------
note    111    Avani    444    Jack
pen     333    Jyothi   555    John
book    222    Nilehi   666    Mohit
```

I tried following query but the records of ASSET column are being repeated

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TABLE1.ARREST), TABLE1.OWNER1, TABLE2.NAME, TABLE1.OWNER2, TABLE2.NAME FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON 
TABLE1.OWNER1 = TABLE2.OWNER OR TABLE1.OWNER2 = TABLE2.OWNER
```

Comment: Join table 2 twice, once on each owner. however you would be better off to normalize table 1 vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the same table twice, with different aliases.

For example:

```
select
  a.asset,
  a.owner1,
  b.name,
  a.owner2,
  c.name
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.owner1 = b.owner
left join table2 c on a.owner2 = c.owner
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT T1.ARREST, T1.OWNER1, T2_1.NAME, T1.OWNER2, T2_1.NAME
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN
     TABLE2 T2_1
     ON t1.OWNER1 = T2_1.OWNER JOIN
     TABLE2 T2_2
     ON T1.OWNER2 = T2_2.OWNER;
```

Often you would use `LEFT JOIN`s for this, in case one of the columns is empty.